# How to display data from service response asp.net

Tags: json, xml, api, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I am working with the earthquake api...
[here](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=xml&starttime=2015-07-27&endtime=2015-07-28&minmagnitude=5)

I am trying to push the "magnitude" and "value" information in a div "earthquake" can be seen here

```
<div id="earthquake"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=xml&starttime=2015-07-27&endtime=2015-07-28&minmagnitude=5", function (dataDD) {
                    console.log(tasks);
                    var tasks = dataDD.list;
                        var html = [];
                        html.push('<div>')
                        html.push(val.description)
                        html.push(val.magnitude.mag)
                        html.push('</div>')
                        $("#earthquake").append(html.join('')).css("background-color", "white");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

But i can't get values right, can some one please help....I am new to xml/json thing and can't put my thoughts into it properly...

Any kind of help will be appreciated....

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net? *curious*

Comment: i thought we could may be work through cs code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably be better advised to change your call to use GeoJSON rather than XML, as this is more easily parsed and queried by JavaScript. You can do this by changing the URL to:

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-07-27&endtime=2015-07-28&minmagnitude=5

Once you have that, you should loop over the `features` array in the returned result, and use `properties.mag` for the magnitiude